# Are there any differences between "Async handlers" and "Non-async handlers" in Lambda node.js runtime?

Tags: aws-lambda

Reading https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html

I noticed that one can use either a "Async handlers" or "Non-async handlers" in Lambda node.js runtime.

But are there any difference from the perspective of the "function invoker"?
Both "Async handlers" and "Non-async handlers" eventually return the same response to the invoker?

Does it just a style of how to write the js code?

Are there any functional differences between the two?
I couldn't find any info from the doc..

Answer (score 0):

They are functionally different in the same way a callback-style and a promise-style function is different in Javascript.

Promises and async/await is mostly the modern way to handle this and probably a good style to default to.

Comment: Thanks, now I know there are some differences there, but can you tell me what's the differences actually are from the perspective of the "function invoker"?